# Send notification from Sharepoint and Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, workflow, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have different content on Sharepoint online and whenever we create or modify any records then send notification to the PHP/Apache server.

I Created one Power Automated notification, but its sending on mobile, need to send to server to server.

Also need to check the Sharepoint REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create API on the server where you want notification from Sharepoint. Then open the Power Automate and create the flow, then

- Select the trigger "When an Item is created or modified".
- In next step search for HTTP and select it.
- Fill the necessary parameters like "Method, URI, Headers, Body" etc.

Then save the flow and test the flow.